# Facebook sends invalid userdata over Omniauth + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

Just two failed login attemps hit my mailbox. Looking at the data the problem was found quickly: Facebook is sending a 11 digit number instead of a email address to my Omniauth-Controller. So the User-Model can't be saved, because its created with a email constraint on the column in the migration file.
Anybody has a idea how I should proceed with the data in such cases? I don't really care if the user has a malformed email address, so I could theoretically just change the column to a normal string etc. Are there better solutions?

Bonus Questions:

- Any other fields known to be unrelieable with the facebook + omniauth + devise
  environment?
- Any fields known to be unrelieable with the
  `google_oauth2` plugin?

Comment: You know you can simply post your own answer and accept that.... You'll still be able to upvote the answer that helped you get to the solution...  The edit you made is not really a good one... It should have been an answer by itself...

Comment: @Lix Thanks I just tought it would be bad netiquette to do so. If you say it isn't good you do so because it was posted in sb. elses answer or do you see technical problems/errors?

Comment: I'm not talking about the technical side - I don't use ruby so I don't really know :) I was just talking about editing your own solution into an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are using a function similar to below...

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                       provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,
                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                       )
  end
  user
end
```

Are you sure auth.info.email is mapped to the correct parameter

EDIT:

Since the above is all fine. I guess the two options are remove the contraint as you say or perform your own check for string or that it contains an @ or whatever and if the data passed is not the correct format you could insert a dummy email address.

Comment: Really similar function yes, and im quite sure it is mapped to the correct parameter because it works with valid params. I also looked trough the malformed request and there is no other field with a valid email address. If it wasn't real data from a user I would have posted it.

Comment: Always best to check these things :)

Comment: JonDay you are absolutely right, I abandoned my belief that you should never trust external data for this omniauth-authentication because I wanted to do it quick. Now I've got bitten (but the fix is quick as well).

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it quick & dirty:

```
# facebook can send malformed/invalid email
email = auth[:info][:email]
unless email =~ /^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/i
email = "#{Time.now.to_i}@MALFORMED_EMAIL.com"
```